# Setting RabbitMqServer (DisablePriorityQueues = true) does NOT have any effect

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

Given this code, I would expect that the Queue mq:Incr.priorityq would not be created. I'm wondering if this setting just disables the use of said queue, but it is still created?

This is from the following [unit tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Server.Tests/Messaging/MqRequestReplyTests.cs)

```
public class RabbitMqRequestReplyTests : MqRequestReplyTests
{
    public override IMessageService CreateMqServer(int retryCount = 1)
    {
        return new RabbitMqServer("cdev-9010.example.com", "test", "test")
        {
            DisablePriorityQueues = true,
            RetryCount = retryCount
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DisablePriorityQueues = true` option prevents spawning any background threads from listening to priority queues, [from the documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#starting-the-rabbit-mq-server):

### Starting the Rabbit MQ Server

Once all your handlers are registered you can start listening to messages by starting the MQ Server:

```
mqServer.Start();
```

Starting the MQ Server **spawns 2 threads** for each handler, one to listen to the Message Inbox `mq:Hello.inq` and another to **listen on the Priority Queue** located at `mq:Hello.priorityq`.

> Note: You can white-list which messages to enable Priority Queue's for with **mqServer.PriortyQueuesWhitelist** or disable them all by setting **mqServer.DisablePriorityQueues = true**.

---

i.e. It doesn't prevent the queues from being created, clients will still be able to send messages to the priority queue, it just means this `mqServer` wont have any threads listening and processing messages that are sent on the priority queue.

Comment: Ahh, just needed you to interpret it for me, as I've read that whole a page a number of times. When I read "disable" I assumed they also wouldn't need to be created. Got it, thanks mythz